# Java object - how to create objects on the fly

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an object like the following...its going to be a response object from a Rest API call.

```
{
    "date": "2020-01-04",
    "oneDayLag": "1.54 ",
    "oneDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "oneDayLagDate": "2020-01-02",
    "twoDayLag": "1.55 ",
    "twoDayLagDayWeight": "2",
    "twoDayLagDate": "2019-12-31",
    "threeDayLag": "1.54 ",
    "threeDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "threeDayLagDate": "2019-12-30",
    "fourDayLag": "1.53 ",
    "fourDayLagDayWeight": "3",
    "fourDayLagDate": "2019-12-27",
    "fiveDayLag": "1.52 ",
    "fiveDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "fiveDayLagDate": "2019-12-26",
    "sixDayLag": "1.52 ",
    "sixDayLagDayWeight": "2",
    "sixDayLagDate": "2019-12-24",
    "sevenDayLag": "1.52 ",
    "sevenDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "sevenDayLagDate": "2019-12-23",
    "eightDayLag": "1.53 ",
    "eightDayLagDayWeight": "3",
    "eightDayLagDate": "2019-12-20",
    "nineDayLag": "1.53 ",
    "nineDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "nineDayLagDate": "2019-12-19",
    "tenDayLag": "1.53 ",
    "tenDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "tenDayLagDate": "2019-12-18"
}
```

I need to create a reduced/slimmed down version of the object depending on the number of days - for example, if the number of days is '4', then the response object should be the following...

```
{
    "date": "2020-01-04",
    "oneDayLag": "1.54 ",
    "oneDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "oneDayLagDate": "2020-01-02",
    "twoDayLag": "1.55 ",
    "twoDayLagDayWeight": "2",
    "twoDayLagDate": "2019-12-31",
    "threeDayLag": "1.54 ",
    "threeDayLagDayWeight": "1",
    "threeDayLagDate": "2019-12-30",
    "fourDayLag": "1.53 ",
    "fourDayLagDayWeight": "3",
    "fourDayLagDate": "2019-12-27"
}
```

I can write a lot of code (a mix of models, services, if-else etc.) to create such objects between the value of 1 and 10, but is there a more elegant way to approach this problem in Java?

Comment: why don't you to use a class `Lag` to present a group of lags? if so, you can slice 1..10 lags just as array slicing.

Comment: lag[0] means "onedaylag" values. Then the reply needs to have some specific lag descriptor added and its not very intuitive. The day descriptor is important for the API consuming application, they will have to do some mapping if I sent them an array and it may cause problems.

Comment: yeah, a Lag consist of `lag`, `weight` and `date` following this way all of the things is simple. Another option (if you can't change the rest api) is parse json as a `JSONObject` from Rest api, and then remove  all unnecessary attributes if its name is not starts with `prefixes = ["one", "two", ..., "ten"]` but except the `date` attribute, in your case the candidates will be `prefixes.slice(0, day - 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As holi-java written - use array.
Example:

```
{
  "date": "2020-01-04",
  "lags": [
    {
      "lag": "1.54 ",
      "lagDayWeight":"1",
      "date": "2020-01-02",
      "lagDay": "1"

    },
    {
      "lag": "1.55 ",
      "lagDayWeight":"2",
      "date": "2019-12-31",
      "lagDay": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And if you are forced to use this really-bad-practice of api, hold values inside your app as list of objects (as in example json), and then create json string by hand using some mapper to map index of object in list to prefix of value in json. But this will hurt you and others in the future. Generating such object is easy - parsing and maintaining it is really annoying.

Comment: Well, what is the other option? Good or bad practice you need to give it back the way  it makes sense. The original response - or the most intuitive response - is easy, but it takes a lot of boilerplate code and is somewhat cumbersome. It is a valid solution.